# does square root of -x has a meaning in R?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had a question earlier, and the question is:

X is a negative number, does the square root of -X has a meaning in R (real numbers)

what's the answer of this question (I know it's a really simple question but I'm confused!)

Comment: If $X$ is negative then $-X$ is positive and so has the usual squareroot in the real numbers.

Comment: so basically the square root of -X has an actual meaning ? ( assuming X is negative)

Comment: The expression $\sqrt{a}$ is defined when $a$ is positive. If $-X$ is positive (i.e. if $X$ is negative), then $\sqrt{-X}$ is defined.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is negative then $-X$ is positive and so has a square root.

I think you are confused because you think that any algebraic expression for a number that starts with a minus sign represents a negative number. That's just not so. If $X = -2$ then $-X = -(-2) = 2$.

Comment: so basically the square root of -X has a meaning (assuming that X is negative)

Comment: @SidalOndsc Yes, because $-X$ is then positive.

Comment: oh alright, thanks then !